# POST with Jersey client using APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED mediatype

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey

I have to post a *pojo* to a server that only accepts parameters via form data (**MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED**). I know jersey client can convert the object to xml, json and other types but trying to convert to APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED gives an exception showing that no body writer for the specified types is available.

Is there a way to serialize the object to be an application_form_urlencoded MultivaluedMap, or i have to manually take attribute by attribute to form the resultant MultivaluedMap? Creating an Adapter to use jersey serialization doesn't seem to me to be the appropriate solution according to the problem context.

**Object to POST**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class POSTableObject {
    private int a;
    private String b;

    public int getA() { return a; }
    public void setA(int a) { this.a = a; }
    public String getB() { return b; }
    public void setB(String b) { this.b = b; }
}
```

**Post Action using Jersey client**

```
ClientResponse response = client.resource(url).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, postableObject);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JAX-RS providers are only required to provide mappings to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for `MultivaluedMap<String,String>`. And I'm pretty sure that out-of-the-box Jersey doesn't provide an additional mapper from `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to regular POJOs. You could write your own client side provider, but depending on how often you need to do this it may be simpler to just map the POJO fields to the URL fields yourself.

Comment: Well, its not a popular use case. A POJO maps more naturally to a multi-level map, whereas `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` really represents a single level map.

Comment: Mapping to a MultivaluedMap<String, String> is enough for my case, i understand that you are saying this can be done not manually?

Comment: If you use a `MultivaluedMap<String, String>` the JAX-RS provider will marshall it automatically. If you use a POJO then you either have to a) manually map it to the request b) Manually map it to a multivalue map (which will then be automatically marshalled) or c) Write a custom client side message body writer.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it but first you have to create an Entity (javax.ws.rs.client.Entity) based on a Form (javax.ws.rs.core.Form) that maps the parameters expected by the service:

```
Form input = new Form();
input.param("first_parameter", "value");
input.param("second_parameter", "value");
Entity<Form> entity = Entity.entity(input, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

ClientResponse response = client.resource(url).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(entity);
```